# Unable to read an Excel file using Pandas

Tags: pandas, openpyxl, xlrd, python-3.11

I can read an Excel file from pandas as usual:

```
df = pd.read_excel(join("./data", file_name) , sheet_name="Sheet1")
```

I got the following error:

> ValueError: Value must be either numerical or a string containing a
> wildcard

What I'm doing wrong?

I'm using: Pandas 1.5.3 + python 3.11.0 + xlrd 2.0.1

Comment: perhaps you meant os.path.join("./data", file_name)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I got the same issue and then realized that the sheet I was reading is in "filtering" mode. Once I deselect "sort&filter", the `read_excel` function works.

Answer (score 1):

For people like me who are wondering what sort and filter is, it is an option in your Excel viewer. If you are using Microsoft Excel, you can go to the tab "Home" and then to the right side of the tab, you can find Sort & Filter, from there select Clear.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I couldn't remove filters from the project. Instead of manually removing filters from files, I was expecting a `"valueError"` exception, then opening the file with `xlrd` and writing to a temporary directory in `.csv` format, then opening with pandas as `csv`

```
    try:
        excel_data_df = pd.read_excel()
    except ValueError:
        with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir:
            workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(f"../registry_dir/{file_name}")
            worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
            with open(f'{tmpdir}/{file_name}.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
                writer = csv.writer(file)
                for row_num in range(worksheet.nrows):
                    writer.writerow([data for data in worksheet.row_values(row_num)])
            excel_data_df = pd.read_csv(f'{tmpdir}/{file_name}.csv')
...file processing code
```

To use `xlrd` to open `.xlsx` files I used `version 1.2.0`

`xrld == 1.2.0`